# TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, wcf

[image: Error]

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:5051/user. The connection
>   attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0600206. TCP error code
>   10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:5051.

Firewall is block? Have any Idea?

Comment: Could be related.. http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/marc/archive/2007/10/23/wcf-hosting-non-http-protocols-in-iis-7-0.aspx

Comment: i think that the firewall block tcp://localhost:5051/user.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the records: correct link for the possible solution linked by @RanjitaDas is
[link](http://blogs.ajithbhat.com/2010/06/tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection.html)